# Forced to use Absolute URLs in Jekyll

Tags: html, css, url, yaml, jekyll

I am trying to set up a personal homepage with Jekyll using the domain provided by my University.

An issue that I have not been able to resolve is Jekyll forcing me to use absolute paths which I believe are not compatible with the webpage hosting service.

The _config.yml file determines how Jekyll generates linkings in the index.html file which is the homepage. _config.yml looks like this...

```
title: Homepage | Ishank Juneja 
email: ishankjuneja@gmail.com
description: >- # this means to ignore newlines until "baseurl:"
Personal homepage Beta version
baseurl: "foobar" # the subpath of your 
site, e.g. /blog
url: "http://home.iitb.ac.in/~ishankjuneja" # the base hostname & protocol for your site, e.g. 
http://example.com
twitter_username: ishankjuneja
github_username:  ishank-juneja

# Build settings
markdown: kramdown
theme: minima
plugins:
- jekyll-feed
```

An example of the (many) linkings it generates in the index.html file is

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/foobar/assets/main.css">
```

[This link](https://kb.iu.edu/d/abwp) explained to me that this is, in fact, an absolute path, which didn't seem like a problem to me, but the Directory Tree on the Web hosting service looks like,

```
public_html
├── 404.html
├── about
│   └── index.html
├── assets
│   ├── main.css
│   └── minima-social-icons.svg
├── feed.xml
├── index.html
└── jekyll
    └── update
        └── 2018
            └── 10
                └── 04
                    └── test-post.html
```

The URL for my homepage `http://home.iitb.ac.in/~ishankjuneja/` is associated with the folder `public_html`, so the path for main.css above would be incorrect. Something like `href="assets/main.css"` works well, but there seems to be nothing that I can type in `_config.yml` to get this result.

Comment: The YAML file your present here is invalid. Is there any particular reason that you use the extension `.yml` (instead of the `.yaml` extension you should use as per the yaml.org website)?

Comment: @Anthon this file was generated when I created a new Jekyll project. Not sure why the extension is so

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In configuration you have to properly set up baseurl:

```
baseurl: "~ishankjuneja"
```

Then use

```
 {{site.baseurl}}page.url
```

Comment: Where are you suggesting I put the second line?

Comment: @ijuneja your generated URLs seem to be using it already so you can omit that step, just adjusting baseurl should work

Comment: It did thank you, for some reason I was convinced that the root url (or url as YML calls it) should be `home.iitb.ac.in/~ishankjuneja`. I thought so since that was the topmost dir that was public. This is incorrect and the topmost dir is in fact `home.iitb.ac.in`

Answer (score 2):

In your example , putting /foobar (the baseurl in _config.yml) is not a good idea.

Using absolute URl is not a good idea either as you have said.

The solution is to use relative_url Liquid Filter as

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href={{"/assets/main.css" | relative_url }} >
```

similar solution as @Aleksandr Kiselev suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Use `{{ page.url | absolute_url }}`

Liquid filters description: https://jekyllrb.com/docs/liquid/filters/